# Can't source .bashrc from .bash_profile when using `sudo su - username -c`

Tags: bash, ubuntu, terminal, sudo

I have the following in my `.bash_profile`:

```bsh
echo bash_profile
if [ -f $HOME/.bashrc ]; then
    echo Sourcing bashrc
    source $HOME/.bashrc
    echo Sourced bashrc
fi
```

My `.bashrc` file is quite long, but at the end I have an `echo Path set` statement and some exports.

When I execute `sudo su - username` I get the following output:

```
bash_profile
Sourcing bashrc
Path set
Sourced bashrc
```

However, when I execute `sudo su - username -c ''` I get this:

```
bash_profile
Sourcing bashrc
Sourced bashrc
```

Why is it that the `source` command stops working with the `-c` flag? I need the changes made to the `PATH` in `.bashrc` when executing a command with `sudo su - username -c`.

Comment: Perhaps your `.bashrc` is checking whether or not the shell is interactive (by looking at the shell options in special variable `$-` for example) and is not processing the rest of the file in the non-interactive case?

Comment: @steeldriver Right on the money. If you add that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: OK thanks - done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.bashrc` file is really intended to be sourced in interactive shells - to allow it to be source in a non-interactive environment such as `bash -c` or `su -c` without error, it's not uncommon to add an "interactivity test" somewhere near the top of the file.

For example, the start of the Ubuntu default `.bashrc` file (copied from `/etc/skel` on account creation) looks like:

```
$ head /etc/skel/.bashrc
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

So, likely your `.bashrc` **is** successfully being sourced - but is returning before reaching the commands that modify your `PATH`.